# SQL Subquery / Subselect getting value from next row without auto increment id or any distinct fields to join on

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

OK, so I have spent hours and hours researching and trying to figure this out.  I've probably read everything SO has on this subject, but nothing fits what I'm trying to do.   I'm not sure if what I'm attempting can be done the way I'm trying to do it, but it seems like it should be.

The main thing that makes this difficult is no unique fields or id's to reference so I have to create my own numbering for the rows.

I have tried so many different things, I can't post them all here,  but any answers would be much appreciated.

Given this table.

```
create table `working_time_table` (

  `id` INT(255),
  `eff_date` VARCHAR(255),
  `percentage` INT(255)

  );

insert into `working_time_table` (`id`, `eff_date`, `percentage`) values (12,'01-JUN-2012',70);
insert into `working_time_table` (`id`, `eff_date`, `percentage`) values (12,'03-MAR-2013',100);
insert into `working_time_table` (`id`, `eff_date`, `percentage`) values (12,'13-DEC-2014',85);
```

I am trying to get a result for each row which looks up the date in the NEXT row and then subtracts one from the date.  So far I have everything figured out except how to get the date value from the next row.

I have added a "currentrow" and "nextrow"  column in the results.   So I am numbering the columns using a variable,  I just can't figure out how to tell the db that I want to get the date for the next column and display it as a result in the current column.

Here is my query...   As you can see I'm getting the correct values for current and next row,  i just need to get the date from the next row and display it on the current row.

You can ignore the stuff for "nd" as that's just parsing the date into a format where i can use DATE_SUB on it.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e4c5/113)

```
SELECT 
    wtt.*
FROM (SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT ( STR_TO_DATE ( CONCAT(
                LOWER(SUBSTRING(`eff_date`,1,3)),
                UPPER(SUBSTRING(`eff_date`,4,1)),
                LOWER(SUBSTRING(`eff_date`,5,7)
            )), '%d-%b-%Y %T'), '%Y-%m-%d %T') 
        AS nd,
       `id`,
        `percentage`,
        `eff_date`,
         t.currentrow,
         t.nextrow

       FROM (SELECT 
                 eff_date, 
                 id, 
                 percentage, 
          (@cnt :=@row_number) currentrow,
                @row_number:=@row_number+1
             AS nextrow
             FROM 
             (SELECT @row_number:=0) as x,
                 working_time_table AS y  
       ) AS t
) AS wtt
```

This gives me the following results...

[image]

Now I just need to figure out how to tell it that I want the date from the next row.   So there should be a column (using the first column "nd" is fine if you want) that has the date for the next row minus one day.  Like so...

[image]

I can use DATE_SUB to subtract the day, I just need to somehow get that date from the row into the current row and I'll be good to go.

I've tried a million things already and none of them have worked.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT id, firstTbl.eff_Date, 
UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(secondTbl.eff_Date, '%d-%M-%Y'), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%d-%b-%Y')) todate, 
percentage FROM 
(SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) rownum, id, eff_date, percentage 
   FROM working_time_table , (SELECT @cnt := 0) s) firstTbl
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT (@cnt1 := @cnt1 + 1) rownum, eff_date 
   FROM working_time_table , (SELECT @cnt1 := 0) s) secondTbl
ON (firstTbl.rownum + 1) = secondTbl.rownum
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e4c5/114/0)

Comment: WOW!  I'm literally amazed at how quickly you answered that and it works great!   You are an SQL Pro!  Thank you so much!  :)    Very nice work.

Comment: Just curious of using DATE_ADD() is better than using DATE_SUB() or  doesn't matter?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Thanks for your kind words !  There is no much difference between DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB. One can follow anything based on their likings